# Using .htaccess to redirect a domain to another URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site running wordpress, it's the full site.  One of the pages is like a contact-us form located at www.ourdomain.com/contact-us/

I also have a URL like contactourdomain.com and I want it to redirect to www.ourdomain.com/contact-us/

We used to do this with a redirect on network solutions, but I prefer to have it all done right on the server if possible.  I've got it sort of working but when you visit the link is still says contactourdomain.com/contact-us/ as the URL, and that breaks all the other ones.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.com/contact-us//$1 [L]
```

Comment: Correct, actually to /contact-us/{original URI}

Answer (score 0):

if you add this in .htaccess is it working?:

```
RewriteRule ^$ contact-us/ [R=301,L]
```

keep me posted..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It sort of works.  I do then end up at the right page the first visit, but then all the links point to contactourdomain.com, when I really want it to just redirect fully to ourdomain.com/contact-us.